# i want to add two row's value in single row

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add two city_name's value (HYD + HYDTC) in HYD

```
CITY_NAME    VALUE
  CCU         10
  CHI         12
  DEL         15
  HYD         20
  HYDTC       30
  MUM         10
```

I want to output in this way:-

```
CITY_NAME    VALUE  
  CCU         10
  CHI         12
  DEL         15
  HYD         50 
  MUM         10
```

Comment: what's logic behind adding these two row's value in single row

Comment: What about situations where there are more than one `HYD` or `HYDTC`?  Are you concerned about other value combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to consolidate rows based on *the first three characters*, then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT LEFT(CITY_NAME, 3) AS CITY_NAME, SUM(VALUE) AS VALUE
FROM mytable
GROUP BY LEFT(CITY_NAME, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
select t.city_name_alt as city_name, sum(t.value) as value from(
    select city_name, 
    case city_name when 'HYDTC' then 'HYD' else city_name end as city_name_alt, 
    value
    from your_table_name
)t
group by t.city_name_alt;
```